# Powershell import-csv to change date format

Tags: powershell, csv, date, time

I'm trying to convert a date through Powershell import-csv and need some help please!
I've simplified the content of the csv file to give an example which appears as:

```
"ServerName","InstallDate"
"SRV1","20220506"
```

Then I use Powershell command:

```
Import-Csv 'c:\results\data.csv' | select servername, installdate
```

The import date is currently in the form of `year/month/date` and I need it converting to `month/date/year` eg `05062022` based on sample data above.

I've experimented with `[datetime]::ParseExtact` but am getting nowhere with it, can anyone help with this?  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming all values in the `InstallDate` column **are populated and follow the same format** then this should work:

```bash
Import-Csv path\to\csv | ForEach-Object {
    $_.InstallDate = [datetime]::ParseExact($_.InstallDate, 'yyyyMMdd', [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture).ToString('MMddyyyy')
    $_
} | Select-Object ServerName, InstallDate
```

Here is an example for testing using hardcoded CSV in a string:

```bash
@'
"ServerName","InstallDate"
"SRV1","20220506"
"SRV2","20220507"
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv | ForEach-Object {
    $_.InstallDate = [datetime]::ParseExact($_.InstallDate, 'yyyyMMdd', [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture).ToString('MMddyyyy')
    $_
}
```

---

In case there *could be* empty values in the column you can add a simple condition to check if [`String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorwhitespace?view=net-7.0), and if it is, ignore that line:

```bash
Import-Csv path\to\csv | ForEach-Object {
    # if the value on `InstallDate` property is empty or white space
    if([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_.InstallDate)) {
        # return this object as-is without any modifications,
        # and go to the next item
        return $_
    }

    # here we assume the property is populated, so we can update it
    $_.InstallDate = [datetime]::ParseExact($_.InstallDate, 'yyyyMMdd', [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture).ToString('MMddyyyy')
    $_
} | Select-Object ServerName, InstallDate
```

Comment: Thanks Santiago Squarzon, that looks perfect. Actually though you raise a very good point.  From my file (which is installed dates of software) I notice some entries are blank in my file and it causes the script to raise an error but it runs through ok and the csv export itself looks good.  Anyway to get the command to ignore blanks?

Comment: hi @user3398681, happy to help. sure, it's a simple `if` condition checking if the value in that column is an empty or all whitespace string - i've updated the code in answer to demonstrate

Comment: Thanks Santiago Squarzon for your excellent assistance, it's appreciated!